# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to run react redux but unfortunately I'm getting undefined error. Here's the error display:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
```

It look like the error is coming from index.js file particulary on Provider store={store} but I could be wrong.

Here's the list of files I have used:

index.js

```
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>  {/*  This will make store accessible to the entire component tree  */}
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pizzaReducer from './pizzaSlice';

const store = configureStore({
reducer: {
pizza: pizzaReducer,
}
})

export default store.reducer;
```

pizzaSlice.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pizzaReducer from './pizzaSlice';

const store = configureStore({
reducer: {
pizza: pizzaReducer,
}
})
export default store.reducer;
```

App.js

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { addTopping, toggleGluten } from './pizzaSlice';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const pizza = useSelector(state => state.pizza);    
  const dispatch = useDispatch();  // dispatch action

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Pizza</h1>
          {
           pizza.toppings.map(toppings => (
             <div key={toppings}>{toppings}</div> 
           ))
         }
         <button onClick={dispatch(addTopping('ham'))}> Add Ham </button>
         <button onClick={dispatch(addTopping('mushroom'))}> Add Mushroom </button>
         <button onClick={dispatch(addTopping('pepperoni'))}> Add Pepperoni </button>
         <button onClick={dispatch(toggleGluten())}> Toogle Gluten </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-sample",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried using createStore from redux but it didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export `store` not `store.reducer`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pizzaReducer from './pizzaSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    pizza: pizzaReducer,
  }
})

export default store;
```